# How can I attach in each header of a fasta file the filename?

Tags: python, r, awk

Dear all I have thousands of ***fasta*** files. When you open each of the files you see headers that look like this:

```
>LOC_1_22 # 16427 # 16873 # 1 # ID=1_22;partial=00;start_type=ATG;rbs_motif=GGAG/GAGG;rbs_spacer=5-10bp;gc_cont=0.635
ATGTTCTTTTATTGCCCGAAGACTGGCGGCTTTTACTCTCCAGAGGTACATGGTGAACAAATGCCAGCGG

>LOC_1_23 # 16964 # 18139 # 1 # ID=1_23;partial=00;start_type=ATG;rbs_motif=GGA/GAG/AGG;rbs_spacer=5-10bp;gc_cont=0.651
ATGGCCGCTGACCAATATCATCACGGTGTCCGGGTCCAAGAGATCAATGACGGGACCCGCCCCATTCGCA
```

**I want to attach to the headers of each file the filename.**
Imagine that my filename is `NC_003245` then I would like the headers of this file
when I open the file to look like this

```
>NC_003245 LOC_1_22 # 16427 # 16873 # 1 # ID=1_22;partial=00;start_type=ATG;rbs_motif=GGAG/GAGG;rbs_spacer=5-10bp;gc_cont=0.635
ATGTTCTTTTATTGCCCGAAGACTGGCGGCTTTTACTCTCCAGAGGTACATGGTGAACAAATGCCAGCGG

>NC_003245 LOC_1_23 # 16964 # 18139 # 1 # ID=1_23;partial=00;start_type=ATG;rbs_motif=GGA/GAG/AGG;rbs_spacer=5-10bp;gc_cont=0.651
ATGGCCGCTGACCAATATCATCACGGTGTCCGGGTCCAAGAGATCAATGACGGGACCCGCCCCATTCGCA
```

My knowledge in bash/awk language in limited,
Any help or advice are hugely appreciated

Comment: i dont understand, so are they csv files ? can you provide more details of what the file structure is

Comment: good point they are fasta files

Comment: could you paste a screenshot of the file?

Comment: What I have placed in my question is exactly the same with the screenshot you ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If if where you I'd do something like this with R:

Let's say you fasta are in one folder that only has the fasta you wanna work with:

```
library(ape)
setwd("path/to/fasta")

for( i in list.files()){
  a = read.FASTA(i)
  names(a) = paste(strsplit(i,'\\.')[[1]][1], names(a))
  write.FASTA(a, file = i)
}
```

Basically, you use a for loop to load fasta (using `ape` package) by calling the file with the `i` object. Then you juste replace the names.

Be careful tho, cause this can overwrite you previous fasta. You can change this by changing the write.fasta parameter (using paste).

Let me know if it's working

Comment: Thank you @elielink for your time. I have upvoted this answer and many others of yours. Thanks for being helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk 'sub(/^>/,"") { $0=">" FILENAME " " $0} 1' NC_003245
```

Where:

- `sub(/^>/,"")` - if a replacement happens for the first character in the line (`^>`) then the `sub()` call is considered 'true' so then ...
- `$0=">" FILENAME " " $0` - redefine the line as `>` + `FILENAME` + `<space>` + `$0` (rest of line); `FILENAME` is a `awk` builtin variable that contains the name of the current input file being processed
- **NOTE:** - updated per comments from Ed Morton

This generates:

```
>NC_003245 LOC_1_22 # 16427 # 16873 # 1 # ID=1_22;partial=00;start_type=ATG;rbs_motif=GGAG/GAGG;rbs_spacer=5-10bp;gc_cont=0.635
ATGTTCTTTTATTGCCCGAAGACTGGCGGCTTTTACTCTCCAGAGGTACATGGTGAACAAATGCCAGCGG

>NC_003245 LOC_1_23 # 16964 # 18139 # 1 # ID=1_23;partial=00;start_type=ATG;rbs_motif=GGA/GAG/AGG;rbs_spacer=5-10bp;gc_cont=0.651
ATGGCCGCTGACCAATATCATCACGGTGTCCGGGTCCAAGAGATCAATGACGGGACCCGCCCCATTCGCA
```

To update the source file, and assuming using `GNU awk`, add `-i inplace`:

```
awk -i inplace 'sub(/^>/,"") { $0=">" FILENAME " " $0} 1' NC_003245
```

Comment: This does not answer my question, since I have multiple files. Thank you for your time @markp-fuso though. I highly highly appreciate

Comment: you provided a single file name in your question so that's what I addressed, with an assumption you knew how to submit multiple files to awk, eg, feed your list of files to `awk` like such: `awk -i inplace '...' file1 file2 file3 ... fileN`, or if all of the files in a specific directory `awk -i inplace '...' /path/to/files/*`